# Paste from word to extjs editor

Tags: javascript, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs3

and i found one more issue with extjs editor.

when i copy the

```html
<ol type="A" style="margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;">
      <li style="line-height: 115%; font-size: 11pt; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 10pt;"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">Main Heading 1</span></li>
   </ol>
   <p style="margin: 0pt 0pt 10pt 72pt; line-height: 115%; text-indent: -18pt; font-size: 11pt;"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">1.</span><span style='font: 7pt/normal "Times New Roman"; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">Item 1</span></p>
   <p style="margin: 0pt 0pt 10pt 72pt; line-height: 115%; text-indent: -18pt; font-size: 11pt;"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">2.</span><span style='font: 7pt/normal "Times New Roman"; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">Item 2</span></p>
   <p style="margin: 0pt 0pt 10pt 72pt; line-height: 115%; text-indent: -18pt; font-size: 11pt;"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">3.</span><span style='font: 7pt/normal "Times New Roman"; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">Item 3</span></p>
   <ol type="A" style="margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;" start="2">
      <li style="line-height: 115%; font-size: 11pt; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 10pt;"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">Main Heading 2</span></li>
   </ol>
   <p style="margin: 0pt 0pt 10pt 72pt; line-height: 115%; text-indent: -18pt; font-size: 11pt;"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">1.</span><span style='font: 7pt/normal "Times New Roman"; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">Item 1</span></p>
   <p style="margin: 0pt 0pt 10pt 72pt; line-height: 115%; text-indent: -18pt; font-size: 11pt;"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">2.</span><span style='font: 7pt/normal "Times New Roman"; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">Item 2</span></p>
   <p style="margin: 0pt 0pt 10pt 72pt; line-height: 115%; text-indent: -18pt; font-size: 11pt;"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">3.</span><span style='font: 7pt/normal "Times New Roman"; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">Item 3</span></p>
```

and pasted in extjs htmleditor, its converted as

```html
<ol style="list-style-type: upper-alpha; direction: ltr;">
      <li style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;">
         <p style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0in; margin-bottom: 0pt; mso-list: l2 level1 lfo1;">Main
            Heading 1
         </p>
      </li>
   </ol>
   <p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
      <br></font>
   </p>
   <ol style="list-style-type: decimal; direction: ltr;">
      <li style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;">
         <p style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0in; margin-bottom: 0pt; mso-list: l5 level1 lfo2; mso-add-space: auto;">Item
            1
         </p>
      </li>
      <li style='color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: "Calibri","sans-serif"; font-size: 11pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;'>
         <p style='color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: "Calibri","sans-serif"; font-size: 11pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0in; margin-bottom: 0pt; mso-list: l5 level1 lfo2; mso-add-space: auto;'>Item
            2
         </p>
      </li>
      <li style='color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: "Calibri","sans-serif"; font-size: 11pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;'>
         <p style='color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: "Calibri","sans-serif"; font-size: 11pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0in; margin-bottom: 0pt; mso-list: l5 level1 lfo2; mso-add-space: auto;'>Item
            3
         </p>
      </li>
   </ol>
   <p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
      <br></font>
   </p>
   <ol style="list-style-type: upper-alpha; direction: ltr;">
      <li style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;">
         <p style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0in; margin-bottom: 0pt; mso-list: l2 level1 lfo1;">Main
            Heading 2
         </p>
      </li>
   </ol>
   <p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
      <br></font>
   </p>
   <ol style="list-style-type: decimal; direction: ltr;">
      <li style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;">
         <p style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0in; margin-bottom: 0pt; mso-list: l7 level1 lfo3; mso-add-space: auto;">Item
            1
         </p>
      </li>
      <li style='color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: "Calibri","sans-serif"; font-size: 11pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;'>
         <p style='color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: "Calibri","sans-serif"; font-size: 11pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0in; margin-bottom: 0pt; mso-list: l7 level1 lfo3; mso-add-space: auto;'>Item
            2
         </p>
      </li>
      <li style='color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: "Calibri","sans-serif"; font-size: 11pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;'>
         <p style='color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: "Calibri","sans-serif"; font-size: 11pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0in; margin-bottom: 0pt; mso-list: l7 level1 lfo3; mso-add-space: auto;'>Item
            3
         </p>
      </li>
   </ol>
```

Please suggest me for this as well, to get rid of formatting issues while copy paste from word to editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I chat with IE support team,I got to know that its not an issue with ExtJs editor, its issue with IE11 engine. If i keep this in IE8 compatibility mode on, it will work.
Please  refer the link
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/7225fe68-5afb-4aa9-a77d-5c4eef366921/copy-paste-issue-in-ie-11?forum=iewebdevelopment

Answer (score 0):

Save the word document in html and copy/paste the html code in "Source Edit".

[image: gif]

[image: view]

```
<ol type="A" style="margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;">
      <li style="line-height: 115%; font-size: 11pt; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 10pt;"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">Main Heading 1</span></li>
   </ol>
   <p style="margin: 0pt 0pt 10pt 72pt; line-height: 115%; text-indent: -18pt; font-size: 11pt;"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">1.</span><span style='font: 7pt/normal "Times New Roman"; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">Item 1</span></p>
   <p style="margin: 0pt 0pt 10pt 72pt; line-height: 115%; text-indent: -18pt; font-size: 11pt;"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">2.</span><span style='font: 7pt/normal "Times New Roman"; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">Item 2</span></p>
   <p style="margin: 0pt 0pt 10pt 72pt; line-height: 115%; text-indent: -18pt; font-size: 11pt;"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">3.</span><span style='font: 7pt/normal "Times New Roman"; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">Item 3</span></p>
   <ol type="A" style="margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;" start="2">
      <li style="line-height: 115%; font-size: 11pt; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 10pt;"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">Main Heading 2</span></li>
   </ol>
   <p style="margin: 0pt 0pt 10pt 72pt; line-height: 115%; text-indent: -18pt; font-size: 11pt;"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">1.</span><span style='font: 7pt/normal "Times New Roman"; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">Item 1</span></p>
   <p style="margin: 0pt 0pt 10pt 72pt; line-height: 115%; text-indent: -18pt; font-size: 11pt;"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">2.</span><span style='font: 7pt/normal "Times New Roman"; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">Item 2</span></p>
   <p style="margin: 0pt 0pt 10pt 72pt; line-height: 115%; text-indent: -18pt; font-size: 11pt;"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">3.</span><span style='font: 7pt/normal "Times New Roman"; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">Item 3</span></p>
```

Comment: Hi, please do it in the IE11, not in chrome browser

Comment: I don't use chrome. I use IE11.

Comment: create same bulletins in word and copy same bulletins into htmleditor and see what will happen, plz do it IE11